# Oculus Quest shows the wrong controller

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, quest, oculusquest

when exporting a demo project (sphere + ovr controller and avatar) to oculus quest, instead of oculus quest controllers, the scene insists to show me the oculus go controller.

I use unity 2018.3.14 and 2019.1.9 oculus integration v1.35 and 1.38.
windows 10.

in oculus rift, the whole scene works perfectly

among the issues this causes
1. controller movement is very limited
2. only 1 hand is shown at a time
2. trigger does not execute the scripts attached to the event.

I followed the proper configuration of oculus scene shown here
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qiJpjnzW-mw&t=1s

in OVRCameraRig -> target devices i tried all options (quest, gear+go and both) but generally made sure its on quest
https://www.dropbox.com/s/chbhpvz5u5fv9b2/oculus%20state.PNG?dl=0
(is there another place where the controller should be set?)

I made sure the right controller is chosen in the models prefab
https://www.dropbox.com/s/ejof63acjlb491z/oculus%20prefabs.PNG?dl=0

I tried to update the integration to v1.39 (only got worse, both controllers became invisible but from the oculus forum that's another problem).

I tried different unity versions.

I tried to factory reset the device.

I tested beat sable to be certain that on other apps the controllers work just fine.

have anyone encountered a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue but resolved by following steps.

1. In Unity menu, Click: Oculus > Tools > Remove AndroidManifest.xlm
2. In Unity menu, Click: Oculus > Tools > Create store-compatible AndroidManifest.xlm
3. In Unity Window, Open: Assets > Plugins > Android > AndroidManifest.xlm.
4. Make sure AndroidManifest.xlm has

   category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"

   but not

   category android:name="android.intent.category.INFO".

Try Build and Run.
Good Luck.